# ¿Cómo puedo Comprimir un JSON hecho en PHP y descomprimirlo en JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cordova, phonegap

Buen día.

Verán, hice una app en apache cordova que lee un JSON hecho en PHP

La app funciona bien y lee el JSON con el algoritmo:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.midominio.com/apiData/JSON.php?' + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
.... inserción de datos en la DB SQLITE con el JSON recuperado
}
```

y en el servidor genero el JSON con PHP usando los algoritmos de...:

```
//se declara que esta es una palicacion que genera un JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
//Se abre el acceso a las conexiones que requieren de esta aplicacion
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

try{
    ... procesos de la base de datos que almacenan datos en una variable $datos;

    // Parseo el string con los datos a JSON
    echo ''.json_encode($datos).'';
    return $datos;

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo  $e->getMessage();

}
```

.

**Y era bastante eficiente hasta hace unos dos meses**, el problema es que la base de datos ha crecido bastante y repite muchas claves, texto etc, etc. esto consume mucho espacio en del JSON:

*Para que me entiendan ocurre el problema que sucede en http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/06/30/compresion-de-json-tecnicas-y-analisis-de-rendimiento/ en el apartado de ***Algoritmo o método básico de compresión*** que dice algo así:*

```
[{
  name : "Andrea",
  age : 31,
  gender : "Male",
  skilled : true
}, {
  name : "Eva",
  age : 27,
  gender : "Female",
  skilled : true
}, {
  name : "Daniele",
  age : 26,
  gender : "Male",
  skilled : false
}]
```

Es decir... el estar repitiendo name, name name, age, age, age, gender gander gender, consume mucho espacio al final en el JSON

¿Conocen alguna manera, de poder comprimir ese JSON en PHP y una vez recuperado por el JavaScript descomprimirlo para obtener nuevamente el original y hacer la inserción en la DB SQLite?.

O, ¿Qué alternativa usarían ustedes?

PST: No puedo modificar la estructura del código de inserción en la APP Cordova (Javascript), por este motivo necesito recuperar el JSON original (descomprimirlo) usando algun plugin, método, o API que me lo permitan.

entonces en resumen quedaría algo así:

Compresión del JSON en PHP -> recuperación de los datos por la APP apache cordova - > descompresión del JSON (Como para leerlo como si fuera originalito) e inserción en la DB SQLITE

de antemano Mil gracias por su ayuda y tiempo de lectura en mi problema.

Por si las moscas, la APP en cordova solo lee ese JSON, no envía datos al servidor, solo la lee, ya que es informativa.

Comment: también trabajo con archivos muy pesados en json, y en base a ello te recomiendo que primero quites la identación, no tienes idea de cuanto reduces con ello, segundo puedes escribir ese json en un archivo y ese archivo comprimirlo. Una vez compreso y con la otra reducción verás la gran diferencia.

Comment: Resulta que herramientas modernas como `Firebase` recomiendan precisamente guardar los datos tal y como los tienes en tu JSON, de forma que para acceder a un elemento en concreto (por ejemplo los datos de `Andrea`) no tengas que recorrer toda la estructura de datos. Leyendo tu pregunta creo que el problema no es el JSON en sí, sino quizá el diseño de tu App o del servicio que recupera los datos, de hecho, es muy raro que en un servicio haya que recuperar todos los datos de golpe. En caso de que fuera necesario con mucha frecuencia entonces se podría pensar en una nueva estructura relacional...

Comment: Se puede comprimir el json con gzip desde php (pero si no puedes modificar el código, esta solución no te va a servir)